# How to create data set from clusters formed in Hierarchical Clustering in python?

Tags: python, hierarchical-clustering, unsupervised-learning

I have formed clusters using hierarchical clustering and want to store those individual clusters separately in a data set for further processing, but I don't know how to do that.

```
Z = linkage(df, 'ward', metric='euclidean')
```

## Creating the Dendrogram

```
plt.figure(figsize=(50, 10))
plt.title('Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram')
plt.xlabel('sample index')
plt.ylabel('distance')
dendrogram(Z, leaf_rotation=90., leaf_font_size=8.,)
plt.show()
```

[Dendrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOegt.png)

## Truncating the clusters

```
plt.title('Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram (truncated)')
plt.xlabel('sample index or (cluster size)')
plt.ylabel('distance')
dendrogram(Z, truncate_mode='lastp', p=12, leaf_rotation=90., leaf_font_size=12.,)
plt.axhline(y=5000, color='r', linestyle='--')
plt.show()
```

[Truncated Dendrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDDKf.png)

Now I want to know that how do I save the four clusters separately or how do i separate them??

Answer (score 0):

## Further create clusters using any of the clustering method

```
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
cluster = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=4, affinity='euclidean', linkage='ward')  
cl = cluster.fit_predict(df)
```

## And then save these clusters in original data frame

```
df['Cluster'] = cl
```

## Now you can sort clusters based on their values